# Missing variable after running regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am working with data that consist of 15 variables or so. One of the variables is typeofdwelling (what type of house it is), within this variable there is 4 type of dwelling (house) Apartment, Attached house, Detached house, and Semi-detached house. So when I run the ln regression I only get typeofdwelling for 3 of the types. Apartment is missing, at first I thought this might be due to the fact there was a space before the word "apartment" in the excel file. I fixed this and then apartment showed up on the regression. However, this time semi-detached house was gone. So i check if there was the same problem in the excel file with this one also, and it was. I fixed it and ran the regression again. This time it went back and apartment was gone again.

the code i am running is this, and what i get is the second picture.

[image]

[image]

dput(yourdata)

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data and code in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: The “missing” level is your reference category. See the comments and answers [to this CV thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/87751/140918) and [an intro from the UCLA stats website](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#dummy).